# Selecting features with NULL attributes in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, query, select-by-attribute, null

How do I identify which features have `NULL` attributes in the attribute table of a shapefile?

When i try `[field]= 'NULL'` it selects the features with `value = 0` (see picture)

[image: example]

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Try replacing the "=" with "is".

I don't have QGIS in front of me, but that is pretty common database select syntax for working with NULL values.

```
pedonal is NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

The field name is "ASSETID", it is either a value or NULL. But actually the field was a text field (KML). I tried..

```
"ASSETID" ISNULL, "ASSETID" IS NULL, ISNULL("ASSETID"), "ASSETID" = ""  NOTHING WORKED!
```

However

```
"ASSETID" = '', "ASSETID" IN ('') did work also for search "ASSETID" in ('2251', '4321' etc)
```

Archaic but workable.

Comment: Whilst this works, I think QGIS needs to improve this somehow - The expression documentation specifically states "To test for NULL use an 
IS NULL
or 
IS NOT NULL
expression."

Answer (score 2):

Instead of "Null",

Try:

```
[FieldName] IS None
```

Answer (score 2):

To select NULL values, click your field. then type in "is NULL." It should look like this: "Field" is NULL. No apostrophe mark (') around the word NULL. Apostrophes are needed around the defined values.