# How to select features where attribute is not NULL?

Tags: qgis, select-by-attribute

I have an OS AddressBase shape file. One of the attributes is 'paoText'. It is either a text string like 'Anchor House' or is NULL.

I want to extract all the records where there is a text string i.e. the attribute is not NULL.

I have tried Advance search with paoText = NULL with the idea of inverting the result to get all those records that contain text i.e. a property name, but my search returns nill records.

I know there are records with NULL in that attribute because I can see them. What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16134/how-to-select-features-with-null-attributes-in-qgis

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Have you tried

```
paoText is NULL
```

or

```
paoText is not NULL
```

Comment: Thanks Rayner those are both answers that work. I hadn't tried those, only the Operators show in the list which does not include IS. I didn't realise I could use IS on its own or with NOT. Thank you

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: Six years later, and `is` is still not one of the options from the list of standard operators in the query builder field... Seems that it would be commonly used by most people to select empty or only filled fields