# Filtering features based on attributes using IS NOT NULL does not seem to work

Tags: qgis, filter, expression

Trying to filter features based on whether one field has value or not.

[image]

After looking up a number of web pages (including the two from this forum), I believe the expression should be:

```
"name" IS NOT NULL
```

However, the above expression returns all the rows.

[image]

When I try `"name" IS NULL`, no row was returned.

[image]

Applying these expressions to other fields yields the same results. Can anyone shed some light on what I might have missed, please?

Relevant threads:
[Selecting features with NULL attributes in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16134/selecting-features-with-null-attributes-in-qgis)
[How to select features where attribute is not NULL?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35149/how-to-select-features-where-attribute-is-not-null/35150)

QGIS version
3.12.3-București

Comment: are your attributes NULL or just empty '' ?

Comment: As @IanTurton said, first inclination is to suspect `name` is `''` not `NULL`. You could check by temporarily adding a virtual field in the field calculator with the expression `length("name")`, which will return `0` if they're `''` and `NULL` if they're really `NULL`.

Comment: Oh my didn't see that coming. Yes, the length of empty cells are all 0! This is OSM export. Does it mean attributes are by default ''? Also, I cannot seem to find the "check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in". Is it because these are categorised as "comments" instead of "answers"? Then how should I close this question?

Comment: Do you use shapefiles? Shapefiles or actually the dBase III format used for storing attributes does not support nulls. See https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/2486 that is somewhat related.

Comment: That would make sense. If NULL is not universally supported, it should be avoided. Thanks, user30184!