# How to Fill blank Fields with other column QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, sql

I have two columns of the same data and I want to unite

for example I have the column "pole_type" and "pole_type_"
and sometimes one has values and some times the other

like seen in the photo

[image]

I want to get all the values in "pole_type_" into "pole_type" so I can delete the first

Iv'e used so far the following rules but not succeeded

```
IF(NULL,"pole_type_","pole_type")
```

or

```
IF("pole_type='',"pole_type_","pole_type")
```

and so on
but I havn't came up with anything that works.

Comment: Assuming empty are blank, not NULL (your second example), try adding a second = and remove the space :  `IF("pole_type"=="","pole_type_","pole_type")`

Comment: Are you able to perform a selection of your data (outside of the calculator) for either blank or NULL?  An example of selecting for NULL is here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16134

Comment: In the screenshots your column is called "/_pole_type" (with an underscore at the start) but your formulas use "pole_type_" (with an underscore at the end).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Welcome to the wonders of [`COALESCE`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_coalesce.asp). Try this:

`COALESCE( "pole_type_" , "pole_type" )`

It will return the first non-null value in a list. If they are all null, it will return null.

Answer (score 6):

You can use:

`CASE
WHEN "pole_type" IS NULL THEN "pole_type_"
ELSE "pole_type"
END`

Answer (score 1):

Another way, less efective, but easy for new users like me, could be:

Select by expression **"pole_type" is NULL**

[image]

Then make your table editable and update field **"pole_type"** with **"pole_type_"**, but only selected features.

[image]