# QGIS filtering a whole field using NOT

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

I'd like to negate some values from my map using the NOT operator.

However, i need to deselect a whole field which contains over 600 entries so I don't want to select each. Is there a way to do this?

Is it possible to use: `NOT SPA_NAME`, without specifying the values

---

Added from answer:

I have a merged layer with many different soil and land use properties. And I'm trying to select areas that meet certain soil and land use conditions.

So far my expression is: `SOIL_TEXTURE = 'clay' OR SOIL_TEXTURE = 'loam' AND LAND_USE = 'arable' AND LAND_USE = 'grassland'`

So now I'd like to make sure special protected areas (SPA_NAME field) are excluded from the selection, but there are so many values that is wouldn't make sense to individually select each.

On closer look I am seeing that the command SPA_NAME IS NULL didn't work. Areas that are under special protection are still being selected

Comment: Could you give some example data/values, because right now I don't really understand your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting features with NULL attributes in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16134/selecting-features-with-null-attributes-in-qgis)

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/157852)

Answer (score 1):

You simply can expand your current expression by `AND "SPA_NAME" IS NULL`.

```
SOIL_TEXTURE = 'clay' OR SOIL_TEXTURE = 'loam' AND LAND_USE = 'arable' AND LAND_USE = 'grassland' AND "SPA_NAME" IS NULL
```

Now it should return all clay and loam areas which are grassy or arable and not within a SPA-area.